# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-router' in '{Project Path}\src'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router

In my vue.js project, I put this code :
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
on the file router.js, but when I try to run the project on browser I always got this error message
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-router' in '{Project Path}\src'

It seem like I didn't install or run this cmd "npm install vue-router" or "npm install vue-router@next" or "npm install vue-router@next --save" which actually I did all of these.

In the command prompt after I run these router installation commands, it seem never reached to 100% complete and I always got the following message :

75 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

7 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 6 high)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.

The question is

1. What did I miss? why I can't install vue-router and why in Youtube, people can do it fine?
2. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Did it actually say that there was an error installing the package? AFAIK that message is a warning about possible vulnerabilities, but it usually does install the package. Try your app again and see if you get the same "Can't resolve..." error.

Comment: I’m not sure, but in the browser console said : “Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ‘vue-router”